# SDL transparent sprite squares

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm using SDL library for game and have trouble with background of sprites.

I have this function for load image:

```
SDL_Surface *loadImage(std::string path) {
  SDL_Surface *image = NULL;
  SDL_Surface *optimizedImage = NULL;

  image = IMG_Load(path.c_str());

  if (image) {
    optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat(image);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
  }

  return optimizedImage;
}
```

When i load sprites

```
image = sdlf::loadImage("images/image_sprites.jpg");
```

they all have squares around them

[for exsample](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.mariomayhem.com/downloads/sprites/smas/smb2-heroes_sheet.png&imgrefurl=http://www.mariomayhem.com/downloads/sprites/mario_all_stars_sprites.php&h=380&w=436&tbnid=PXy3LDhB3dhuyM%3a&zoom=1&docid=KnJQoMLSAEm5SM&ei=d6A4U67_Io_s0gXCi4GoDg&tbm=isch&ved=0CPwBEIQcMDU&iact=rc&dur=702&page=2&start=40&ndsp=45)

inside the loop

```
sdlf::apply_surface(0, 0, image, screen, subj.getClipRun(i));
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of these squares?

Do we need to use SDL_SetColorKey function for this goal?

Comment: Do you use jpeg images as sprites? They don't support transparency. You should use png images which supports transparency, and SDL can handle them as well. If you really want to use jpeg images, you need to define a color key. The pixels with that color will then be transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please dont use `JPEG`s when making game art, it deteriorates the images and makes them look worse. Please use a format like `BMP`(or `PNG` if you want to save space). If your sprite has less than 256 different colors (aka 8bit image) you can use a `GIF` image.

If you insist on using a JPEG image then you HAVE to use `SDL_SetColorKey()`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use JPG files!

You could use "SDL_image 2" to handle png files or just use bitmaps.

In order to use the color key, simply add

SDL_SetColorKey(image, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB(image->format, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF)); (I am using cyan here)

So it would be something like:

```
   SDL_Surface *loadImage(std::string path) {
   SDL_Surface *image = NULL;
   SDL_Surface *optimizedImage = NULL;

   image = IMG_Load(path.c_str());

   SDL_SetColorKey(image, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB(image->format, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF));

   if (image) {
    optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat(image);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
   }

   return optimizedImage;
}
```